# How to save a boolean state in main.dart so it is retained throughout app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a challenge in retaining a boolean value state in my dashboard screen after I close or reload app.

On the dashboard screen, there is a ListTile where I can mark a card as verified by tapping on that card. Once the card is tapped, I set the bool verified state from false to true which works fine as long as I haven't closed or reloaded the app. Once the app is closed or reloaded, the boolean state is set back to false.

How can I initialize the boolean state in `main.dart` so that the verified status is always retained once it is set from the dashboard screen and can be used anywhere (more screens) within the app

here is the code:

**Dashboard screen**

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  
  bool _verified = false;


  //Retrieving card info from database
  bool isFetching = false;
  late String cardInfo = retrieveData;  //url to php script for retrieving from database

  List cardData = [];

  getCardData() async {
    setState(() => isFetching = true);
    
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(cardInfo));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        cardData = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
    setState(() => isFetching = false);

    return cardData;
  }

  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

   getCardData();

    _verified;
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('Approve Card'),
centerTitle: true,
),

body: Container(
                  child: Card(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        primary: false,
                        itemCount: cardData.length, //coming from mysql database
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              height: 50,
                              width: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                      'http://url/uploads/${cardData[index]['logo']}'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text(
                              cardData[index]['name'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              cardData[index]['email'],
                            ),
                            trailing: Bounce(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                              onPressed: () { //onPressed set verified state to true
                //After app is reloaded, it is set back to false
                                setState(() {
                                  col = iconTip;
                                  _verified = true;
                                });

                                var url = Uri.parse(verifiedCards), //http url to php script
                                    response = http.post(url, body: {
                                      "card": cardData[index]['card'],
                                    });

                                getCardData();

                              },
                              child: Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                color: col,
                                child: Icon(Icons.check_sharp),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
);

}

}

}
```

**Main.dart screen**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: My Flutter App,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          backgroundColor: white,
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const SplashScreen(),
        
        '/dashboard': (context) => const Dashboard(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to save the state entire the application then you need to be used "Provider package". Please Check the Documentation https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Yes, I'll like to save throughout app

Answer (score 0):

Use the shared_preferences package to save data that needs to persist between app reloads.

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

```
// Save value
await prefs.setBool('verified', true);

// Read value 
final bool? verified= prefs.getBool('verified');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change your application state entire application then you can use [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

1. First create Model Class

```
class MyChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool _verified;

  void setVarified(bool verified){
   _verified = verified;
   notifyListeners();
  }
  bool get verified => _verified;
}
```

2. Attach Notifier with `main.dart` file.

```
runApp(MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<MyChangeNotifier>(create: (_) => MyChangeNotifier()),
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
));
```

3. Use State in your application

```
// For change State from widgets
ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
      context.read<MyChangeNotifier>().setVarified([true / false]);
    }, child: Text('Event Setter'));

// Access State for widget
bool check = context.read<MyChangeNotifier>().verified;
```

Also, you can check [Flutter State Management in Hindi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8rlGbkX6EM) video tutorial for more help.

Answer (score 0):

A complete example with Shared Preference :

Writing boolean value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool('isfirstRun', false);
```

Reading boolean value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool myboolean = prefs.getBool(key) ?? true; // Or false depending of what you want for default value. This is required for Null safety
```

And don't forget to import share preference package:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers, I appreciate. I figured it out with the shared preferences I onced used. I was thinking there was a way to do so without using shared preferences but since it does the work and it's not too complicated, I decided to use it